# Failed a review audit that has a close vote

Tags: bug, status-deferred, review, review-audits

[This audit](https://askubuntu.com/review/close/257140) was failed, even trough the question has a close vote, and I was the one that casted the close vote. Why I'm shown an audit about a question I'm trying to close anyways?

Comment: strange, that seems a bit fresh to be an audit...

Answer (score 4):

This is just an edge-case that, frankly, most folks will never hit.

Audits are generated based on criteria that avoid posts with close votes. And review tasks associated with posts that *you've* voted to close are filtered out for you. *However...*

If the system generates an audit for you, and you open the post and vote to close it, *and then jump back into review...* You'll still have the audit there, waiting for you to review it.

Which you did. And then promptly failed it by trying to vote *again*.

Comment: Actually no, I had voted that 20 minutes before hitting the audit, which at first looks weird.

Comment: I checked the logs before answering here, because I take bug reports seriously. I know what you did, and when you did it. There was a 20-minute gap between you first encountering that question in review and returning to it, but the sequence of events is exactly as I described it here.

Comment: Well, I've checked my own activity and I don't think I found that Q through the queue, since after voting to close I edited other 8 questions and then hit the audit. If I forgot, maybe, but I don't tend to leave the close queue tab opened for that long. What I'm sure is that when in the queue, I went out the queue to check the question again before clicking "close".

Comment: Ah, I think I see the point of confusion: you didn't leave the tab open. But when you're assigned an audit, it tends to stick around for a while - unless you complete it, skip it, or someone else is assigned it. So when you re-entered review 20 minutes later, that audit was still there waiting for you.

Comment: Mm... that sounds plausible, then.